# Comments with start conditions (flex)

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I'm doing a compiler with flex and bison and I have to allow comments using //.
I'm using start conditions with flex but it doesn't work.

Code:

```
%x comentario2

%%

"//"    {BEGIN(comentario2);}

<comentario2>[^\n]

<comentario2>\n {BEGIN(INITIAL);}
```

Comment: Please be more specific. How does it not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in my bison code I use this grammar for a line:

```
expr NX_LINE
```

and in my flex code I wasn't returning the token at the end of the line. The correct flex code is:

```
"//"    {BEGIN(comentario2);}

<comentario2>[^\n]

<comentario2>\n {++num_linea;printf("\n");BEGIN(INITIAL);return NX_LINE;}
```

Answer (score 1):

In flex, `.` means exactly the same thing as `[^\n]` (any character except newline).

Also, your start condition is pointless. It is simply doing the equivalent of a Kleene star (the `*` regex operator), so you don't need it at all. Just use the rule:

```
`//.*`
```

(with no action).

The `\n` which terminates the comment will not be matched by that rule, so it will be handled correctly by whatever rule you generally use to recognize it. It will then be passed on to the grammar without any additional effort on your part.